# Java JPA with Hibernate Mapping for Class

Tags: java

Say I have

```
class Properties {
    private final MediaType mediaType; // javax.ws.rs.core;

    public MediaType getMediaType() { return mediaType; }
}
```

When this is saved into the SQL, it gets saved as

```
"type": "application",
"subtype": "x-www-form-urlencoded",
"parameters": {
    "charset": "utf-8"
},
"wildcardType": false,
"wildcardSubtype": false
```

How can I make this return `toString` version of the MediaType?

Comment: Whats you entity? properties? how are you saving it?, you should have an ID if that class is an Hibernate Entity, also, you must do the converters for objects that are not the default http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your entity code (or you're using Hibernate with xmls) but you do need to create a converter in which you implement conversion methods for both directions:

1. Convert entity to database representation  (that is, convert `MediaType` to its `toString`
2. Convert database representation (string) to the entiry. This direction will be harder for you as you'll need a `json` mapper for that.

Here's an example of [how to implement converters](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)